# Rails 4: Displaying tables related with user_id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, view, foreign-key-relationship, table-relationships

I am trying to create a resume builder. Inside the resume, I would like to display the *first* corresponding `Job` *title* to a specific `User` in the `show.html.erb`.

I first made sure that Jobs has the user_id foreign key..

## Schema

```
create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "company"
    t.date     "date_start"
    t.date     "date_end"
    t.boolean  "current"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "career_id"
end
```

..and the relationships are like so:

## User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  
        has_one :career
        has_many :jobs, through: :career
end
```

## Job Model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :descriptions
end
```

## Controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(1)
end
```

What is the best way to go about this? I was able to display other elements such as Name and Contacts on the same Show View page. I have tried a ton of different lines but currently have this...

## Show View

```
<%= @user.jobs.first.title %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Job model has belongs_to :user, which would mean your jobs table needs a user_id attribute.

I don't know how your Career model looks like, but it seems you don't need

```
has_many :jobs, through: :career
```

if you're tying the job directly to the user via user_id (which should be added to your jobs table). In other words,

```
has_many :jobs
```

might just work. However, if you need to stick to Career, then make sure that

```
class Career < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :jobs
end
```

And then, from your view do:

```
<%= @user.jobs.first.title %>
```

Comment: I realized the Career model was unnecessary, so this worked out perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Join Table**

What you're looking at is a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship:

[image]

As such, you'll be better with the following setup -

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | etc | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :careers
   has_many :jobs, through: :careers
end

#app/models/career.rb
class Career < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | job_id | career_id | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :job
   belongs_to :career
end

#app/models/job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | title | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :careers
   has_many :users, through: :careers
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find
   end
end

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= @user.jobs.first.title %>
```